# Sorting in Data using Custom Sort & Filter based on Column Values

Tags: excel, vba

I'd like to filter a data set based on Column 1, then sort by custom sort in column 2.
Column 1 sorts out the 0's leaving 1's. Column 2 will be sorted in the order (Complete, HOT, On-Going, Follow-Up)

| Column 1 | Column 2 |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | On-Going |
| 1 | HOT |

So far I have gotten my filter to work properly, but cannot get my custom sort to work.

```
Worksheets("BoardItems").AutoFilterMode = False
'Worksheets("BoardItems").Range("A1:J1").AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="1"
Worksheets("BoardItems").AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("E2:E350"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, _
    CustomOrder:="Complete,HOT,On-Going,Follow-Up", DataOption:=xlSortNormal
Worksheets("BoardItems").Sort.Apply
```

I either obtain a "Object expected" error, or a "Object variable or with block variable not set" error.
I do utilize a sort function earlier in the program to sort by value in column A, but im (fairly) certain that I clear the filter before attempting to insert these 2 new ones.

*Edit ~*
I Should mention this is not a table but excel values. Additionally I'd like to sort by 2 columns. I know the sort / filter options can get a little conflicting when there is more than 1 so please let me know the rules around them.
I'd like Priority to be sorted by "Hot,Follow-Up" and Status by "Complete,On-Going,NEW"
Here is my attempt

```
'Filter by Report and Sort by Priority, Select and Print
Worksheets("BoardItems").AutoFilterMode = False
'Filter Report Column
Worksheets("BoardItems").Range("A1:J1").AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="1"

'Sort based on Priority
Worksheets("BoardItems").Sort.SortFields.Clear
Worksheets("BoardItems").AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("E:E"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, _
    CustomOrder:="HOT,Follow-Up", DataOption:=xlSortNormal
Worksheets("BoardItems").Sort.Apply
'Sort based on Status
Worksheets("BoardItems").AutoFilter.Sort.SortField.Add Key2:=Range("I:I"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, _
    CustomOrder:="Complete,On-Going,NEW", DataOption:=xlSortNormal
Worksheets("BoardItems").Sort.Apply
```

Here is a snapshot of the excel sheet before sorting
[image]

and after
[image]

Comment: `Worksheets("BoardItems").AutoFilter.Sort` is wrong. `Sort` is a method of the `Range` object; it is Not a method (or property) of the `Autofilter` object.  The error message is because you have not set an object for `Sort` to act onl.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer using Table references vs range references, and the following seems to work sorting `Column2` of the table `Table9` by the custom order.

Hopefully you can adapt this to your actual situation.

```
Worksheets("BoardItems").ListObjects("Table9").Sort.SortFields.Clear
Worksheets("BoardItems").ListObjects("Table9").Sort.SortFields.add _
        Key:=Range("=Table9[[#All],[Column 2]]"), _
        SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, _
        Order:=xlAscending, _
        DataOption:=xlSortNormal, _
        CustomOrder:="Complete,HOT,On-Going,Follow-Up"

    With Worksheets("BoardItems").ListObjects("Table9").Sort
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
End Sub
```

***Before***
[image]

***After***
[image]

Comment: Sorry, I think my first example wasn't fully detailed. I have tried this method and it "appears" to apply to the cell at the top, but the order doesnt actually change. I have updated my post with some more information, thank you.

Comment: @TheGarbinger I would look at your updated example if you post the "before" as text that can be copy/pasted. [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question)